# Getting information about installing packages

Tags: linux

```
F14 2.6.35.6-48.fc14.x86_64
```

I went to install skype for linux and when I ran the rpm package it failed as it needed the following library qt4-x11. So I wanted to get some information about this library before I installed it. So I did the following:

```
yum info qt4-x11
```

It came back with no packages listed for this.

So a bit of searching on the Internet, and I found this works when I install it.

```
yum install qt4-x11
```

However, why doesn't it list info about this package, but I can install it without any problems with the same name?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this:

- http://pkgs.org/fedora-14/fedora-i386/qt-x11-4.7.0-3.fc14.i686.rpm.html

it was renamed from `qt4-x11` to `qt-x11`. You can also confirm this yourself:

```
$ yum whatprovides qt4-x11
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
1:qt-x11-4.6.2-16.fc13.i686 : Qt GUI-related libraries
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Other       : qt4-x11
```

which says "qt-x11 is providing qt4-x11". It's probably a "feature" `yum show` doesn't recursively search the aliased packages.

As a side note, this was probably a question for http://serverfault.com - stackoverflow.com is for programming questions.